# Get Facebook and Instagram posts on Android app without User login without using Access Tokens

Tags: java, android, instagram, access-token, instagram-api

I'm developing an Android app and need some help with it. I'm trying to get Facebook and Instagram posts on my app without making user to sign in to their respective accounts. Is it possible to show posts of any public pages present on for both Facebook and Instagram into my app and if yes, then how?

This may sound like it's already been asked but I couldn't find solution to my current problems. If I missed it,then please share link below for me to solution.

Thanks for helping in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link for user's information:
https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1

Parse in Android with Json Parse. But if profile is secret, you can not see the post without APİ login. No way to resolve it.

Comment: I want posts of public pages only, so I will try your suggestion. And can you help with Facebook posts? Or is it same and just replace Facebook with Instragram? Thanks for helping!!

Comment: You can also get posts with this link. About Facebook I do not know much things. Search Facebook graph api please.

Comment: Above method just shows last 12 posts or single page. Anyway to jump to next page and loop over to get all posts?